# How do I adjust the speed of an animation?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to create a bouncing ball in which I can adjust the speed it bounces

Here is my original code

```
 <script>

      var context;
      var x=100;
      var y=200;
      var dx=5;
      var dy=5;


      function init()
      {
         context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
         setInterval(draw,100);
      }


      function draw()
      {
        context.clearRect(0,0, 300,300);
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle="#B76EB8";
        // Draws a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
        context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        if( (x-20)<0 || (x+20)>300) dx=-dx; 
        if( (y-20)<0 || (y+20)>300) dy=-dy; 
        x+=dx; 
        y+=dy;

  }
</script>
```

However I found that the animation lags, when I decrease the ball speed via setInterval

So I used

```
  function init()
  {
    context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    (function animloop(){

      requestAnimFrame(animloop);
      draw();
      setTimeout(animLoop, 1);

    })();

  }
```

to make the animation smoother

But now I can't adjust the speed of the bouncing ball at all, are there other suggested ways I can achieve my goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout/interval should be no less than say about 20ms and the animation function should animate based on the *delta-time elapsed*. This will result in a consistent animation (a discrete position function can be even better, but a simple delta-time approach often works well enough).

Then the overall ball speed can be controlled over (and independently of) any interval amount. Remember the formula: `d = d0 + v * t`. The original code is missing the `t` (*delta-time*) component and `x+=dx` is effectively equivalent to `x = x0 + dx * 1`. However, the time between intervals need not be constant and should be compensated for with a bit of math.

Consider [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tbYCp/3/):

```
var interval=20;
var x=100;
var y=200;
var dx=100/1000; // px/1000millis
var dy=100/1000;

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var w=canvas.getAttribute("width") || 0;
var h=canvas.getAttribute("height") || 0;

var prevTime = +(new Date)
function draw()
{
    var now = +(new Date)
    var delta = now - prevTime;
    if (delta < 5) {
       // Timeout occured too fast, we could be "stacking"
       // setInterval events, abort!
       return;
    }
    prevTime = now;
    // We now have "delta time millis" to get work done

    // Do movement before draw
    // (This bound check can actually get the
    //  ball stuck, but that's a different question!)
    if( (x-20)<0 || (x+20)>w ) dx = -dx;
    if( (y-20)<0 || (y+20)>h ) dy = -dy; 
    // Apply delta time
    x = x + dx * delta;
    y = y + dy * delta;

    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle="#B76EB8";
    context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();

}

// Uset setInterval because it will "reprime" the next timeout
// callback faster and more consistently.
setInterval(draw, interval);
```

Note that changing the interval delay will make the animation smoother, but it will *not* affect the overall ball movement speed (this is a bit of a lie due to how the edge collision is handled). Try changing the interval from 20 to 10, 50, 100 and observe the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you elaborate more on the delta? Why is `var delta = now - prevTime;` necessary? Since we have constant step time, isn't delta always the same?

Comment: @xbd It's not constant time between callbacks. It's [usually] "close to" the interval timeout, but it need not be exact. Using setTimeout vs. setInterval exaggerates the problem a bit more. Anyway, even the defined interval itself need not be constant - change it from the 20millis above. Using the delta-time approach means that the speed of the ball/world can be controlled independently of the number of updates/seconds (i.e. `setInterval(,20)` or `setInterval(,100)` should behave about the same) because the ball is updated in accordance with how much time has elapse *since* the last update.

Comment: @xbd Since dx/dy are now values *in relation to* time, changing them changes the speed of the ball, independent upon the interval, due to the application of elapse/delta-time in the update formula.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although after testing it out it worked, I still don't see how dx/dy is in relation to time, intuitively, increasing dx/dy, means that it will increase the step of distance relative to the last distance, therefore if you increase dx/dy, the ball will theoretically jump around, and decreasing setInterval reduces the time that it updates, therefore increase the repetition that the ball is draw, but since every time the ball is draw the position is updated, the speed of the ball increases, I don't get why it is the opposite

Comment: @xbd Consider these unit annotations: `dx = (pixels)/(seconds)`, `x = (pixels)`, `t = (seconds)`. so `x = x + dx * t` is `x = (pixels) + (pixels)/(seconds) * (seconds)` -> `x = (pixels) + (pixels)` -> `x = (pixels)`. The key is that the amount of *time* applied (to a measurement of movement/time which yields a distance) changes based upon how much time is elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want less "jitter" at the expense of slower movement in your animation then set dx & dy ==1.

That way the user views the ball move in small increments rather than "jumps".

You might consider using requestAnimationFrame to run your animation loop.  It gives you a timestamp which you can use to throttle your animation to various frames-per-second:

Here's example code:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Y9bYv/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

        var x=100;
        var y=200;
        var dx=1;
        var dy=1;

        var start;
        var fps=30;
        var delay=1000/fps;

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);;

        function draw(){
          context.clearRect(0,0, 300,300);
          context.beginPath();
          context.fillStyle="#B76EB8";
          // Draws a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
          context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
          context.closePath();
          context.fill();
        }


        function animate(time) {

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            if(start===null){start=time;}

            var elapsed=time-start;

            if(elapsed<delay){return;}

            draw();

            start=time;

            x+=dx; 
            y+=dy;

            if(x<20){ dx=-dx; x=20; }
            if(x>280){ dx=-dx; x=280; }
            if(y<20){ dy=-dy; y=20; }
            if(y>280){ dy=-dy; y=280; }
        }

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```